# How To extract Value from Json multi dimension Array In MySQL

Tags: mysql

column contain value given below.

```
 [
  {
    "bActive": false,
    "sSubLocation": "",
    "aiSeries": [],
    "iUser": "1"
  },
  {
    "bActive": true,
    "sSubLocation": "Mytestcase",
    "aiSeries": [],
    "iUser": "1"
  }
]
```

I want to get result as sSubLocation key where it have bActive =true and sSubLocation = "Mytestcase";

Comment: Don't use JSON to store data you need to query on, particularly where you have multi-dimensional arrays. Create proper tables for the data. The query for this would be trivial if you'd set up your tables properly.

Comment: Parse (use JSON_TABLE function) then query to separate values.

Comment: * i want to get result as **sSubLocation** key where it have bActive =true and **sSubLocation = "Mytestcase"**;* ???

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT test.id, jsontable.*
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.value,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (bActive BOOLEAN PATH '$.bActive',
                                      sSubLocation VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.sSubLocation',
                                      aiSeries JSON PATH '$.aiSeries',
                                      iUser VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.iUser')) jsontable
HAVING bActive = true 
   AND sSubLocation = 'Mytestcase'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcf7f238e23a2c282cdea76c183ae8fa

Comment: This seems not working on Mysql Version 5.7.4.

Comment: Thanks Akina, but it have error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(test.value,
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (bActive BOOLEAN PATH '$.bActi' at line 3.

Comment: @amitchauhan Maybe your MySQL version is too ancient? you have not specified it..